# moi or moî, which is it and does it matter?

Tags: orthographe

I have seen both the accented and unaccented version in use and I'm beginning to wonder which is the right version. My first thought was that maybe both are right but the accented one is becoming obsolete because of the push to remove the accent circonflexe (heard it mentioned somewhere in my course)... but I'd like some clarification.

Comment: Le mot moî n'existe pas en français. Où tu as vu cette écriture ?

Comment: Au passage en nouvelle orthographe l'accent circonflexe n'est plus conseillé dans de nombreux mots : https://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/regles4.htm

Comment: Don't remember a specific place to reference but I've seen it quite a  few times in different places e.g in books, subtitles, on the internet

Answer (score 6):

« Moî » n'existe pas en français.

Il faut utiliser « moi »

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Ingasha: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Où tu as vu cette orthographe ? Ça agit probablement de fautes de frappe. *Moî* n'est pas un mot français. L'écriture correcte est *moi*. En revanche, *moï* existe en français. Voir : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mo%C3%AF
Auparavant moy existait aussi https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moy#Fran%C3%A7ais

Comment: *Moy* aussy ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Mercy bien:-)!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

For those of us not proficient in French, let me save you the translating time...Basically Moî does not exist ; it's moi.
Any place you may have seen Moî as French was probably a typo.